# How to use websocket in koa to return data to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, koa

I set up a connection using websocket and listened to the "message" event to get the data. At this time, I wanted to return the data to the client through ctx.body, but the client could not receive it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv7zg.png)

I tried passing the data to the next middleware and then returning the data to the client, but it didn't work